# Integral $\int \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}$

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I want to determinate the following integral

$$\int \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx \space | \space a> 0$$

I used integration by partition and u-substitution but I came to no result.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533082/integral-of-sqrt1-x2-using-integration-by-parts

Comment: @lab It's only related in that it involves trig substitution. In that post, the substitution is $x = \sin \theta$.

Comment: @amWhy, the relation also lies in integrating by parts, otherwise how would you finish of the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x = a \tan \theta$. Then $dx = a \sec^2 \theta d \theta$, and you have:

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{(a \tan \theta)^2 + a^2}(a \sec^2 \theta) d \theta 
&= \int \sqrt{a^2(\tan^2 \theta + 1)}(a \sec^2 \theta) d \theta \\
&= \int (a \sec \theta)(a \sec^2 \theta) d \theta \\
&= a^2 \int \sec^3 \theta d \theta 
\end{align}$$

Now integrate by parts:
$$\begin{align}
u &= \sec \theta &dv &= \sec^2 \theta d\theta \\
du &= \sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta &v &= \tan \theta 
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\int \sec^3 \theta d \theta &= \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec \theta \tan^2 \theta d \theta \\
&= \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec \theta (\sec^2 \theta - 1) d \theta \\
&= \sec \theta \tan \theta - \int \sec^3 \theta d \theta + \int \sec \theta d \theta \\
\Rightarrow 2 \int \sec^3 \theta d \theta &= \sec \theta \tan \theta + \int \sec \theta  d \theta \\
\Rightarrow \int \sec^3 \theta d \theta &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sec \theta \tan \theta + \ln \left|\sec \theta + \tan \theta\right|\right)+C
\end{align}$$

So then you have:

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} dx &= a^2 \int \sec^3 \theta d \theta \\
&= \frac{a^2}{2}\left(\sec \theta \tan \theta + \ln|\sec \theta + \tan \theta|\right)+C  
\end{align}$$

Now since $\tan \theta = \frac{x}{a}$, and $\sec \theta = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a}$, you have:

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} dx &= \frac{a^2}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a} \frac{x}{a} + \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a} + \frac{x}{a}\right|\right)+C \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(x\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + a^2 \ln \left|\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} + x\right|\right)+C'
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Try trigonometric substitution by letting $x = a\tan \theta \implies dx = a\sec^2 \theta$.

You can then use the fact that $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Using integration by parts, you simply have$$\int \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx =\int \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot 1dx
\\I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x-\int x\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} dx
\\  I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x-\int  \frac{x^2+a^2-a^2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} dx
\\ I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x-I+a^2\int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} dx
\\ 2I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x+a^2\int  \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}\cdot \frac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} dx
\\ 2I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x+a^2\int  \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}\cdot( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}+1) dx
\\ 2I= \sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}\cdot x+a^2\ln (x+\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}})+c$$