# How to evaluate $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ without assuming $x=\sin \theta$?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate $$\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Without assuming $x=\sin \theta$

I tried evaluating by parts but i am not getting.

From by parts, I am getting $$\dfrac{x^3}{3\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1/3\int{\dfrac{x^3}{{\left(1-x^2\right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = x \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, then integrate by parts.

Comment: @πr8 i am getting $=\dfrac{x^3}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1/2\int{\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}}$ dont know if i am wrong

Comment: @Fawad first of all you do not *assume* $x=\sin \theta$. Second, when you use direct formula of $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ or $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$... note that these are derived using $x=\sin \theta$ or $x=\cos \theta$ or some other trig function...

Comment: @MANMAID well, guessing might be the way without trig substitution, to evaluate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx $$

Comment: @BAI I guess you are saying $2=(1-x)+(1+x)$ ... or can you tell me how(I want to know!)

Comment: @MANMAID by using parts. Look at Yves Daoust answer.

Comment: @Fawad can you evaluate derivative of $\arcsin x$ without involving trig function... if so then you can obviously integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ without using trig ...( I guess you understand what I am saying)

Comment: @Fawad There are two ways of doing integration by parts ... try differentiating the first factor and integrating the second.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html

Comment: Related  : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533082/integral-of-sqrt1-x2-using-integration-by-parts/533087#533087

Comment: @MANMAID I'm saying that, the integration of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ should be recognized as a pattern for someone had found the derivative of $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1-(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx.$$

Then by parts

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+I,$$ so that

$$I=\frac12\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-\frac12x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

Now if you don't recognize the derivative of the $\arcsin$ in $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, you absolutely can't avoid the substitution with $\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$=-\int x\,\mathrm d\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$=-x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx 
$$
The latter integral could be taken as granted (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533082/integral-of-sqrt1-x2-using-integration-by-parts) for an approach without using trigonometric substitution to this integral), and get
$$=-x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac12 (\sin^{-1}x+x\sqrt{1-x^2})+c$$
$$=\frac12 (\sin^{-1}x-x\sqrt{1-x^2})+c$$

Comment: Sorry but i didnt understood first step.

Comment: @Fawad $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int x\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\int x\frac{d\sqrt{1-x^2}}{dx}dx$$