# Find the volume of the region common to the interiors of the cylinders

Tags: integration, 3d

First cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$
Second cyclinder $x^2+z^2=4$

My progress so far
$$V=8\int_0^2\int_0^\sqrt{4-y^2}\int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2}dzdxdy$$
I know I can substitute $x$ with $2\sin(\theta)$ in $\int\sqrt{2-x^2}$ but if I do that then I came across $sin(4\sin\theta)$ after substituting $y$ with $2\sin\theta$ in $\int_0^\sqrt{4-y^2}\cos^2\theta$

Comment: Yeah...hopefully somebody will promptly fulfill your orders, sir.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include my work, wait a minute

Comment: Where did the 9 and the 3 come from? This looks like perhaps the solution to an example problem.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I fixed it

Comment: @ Deniz da King Why are you using 9 instead of 4?

Comment: @DenizdaKing I've already indicated to you the same resource in the previuos OP, read it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533082/integral-of-sqrt1-x2-using-integration-by-parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a triple integral to find the volume.

$$ V= 8\int _0^2 \int _0^{\sqrt {4-x^2}}\int _0^{\sqrt {4-x^2}}dzdydx$$

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah No, the OP changed the question to match what Mohammad wrote down.

Comment: My bad, the answer appeared much later for me.

Comment: @Mohammad might be a silly question but, how did using same $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ as upper limit on both inner integrals worked? Is it same as using $\sqrt{4-y^2}$ on middle integral?

Comment: @DenizdaKing The middle one comes from $y=\sqrt {4-x^2}$ and the last one comes from $z=\sqrt {4-x^2}$

Comment: Ooh I see, I messed up the order. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fact that the cross-sections parallel to the $yz$ plane are squares, find the area $A(x)$ of those squares and then find the volume using

$$ V=\int_{-2}^2 A(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

You may use polar coordinates,

$$V= 8\int _0^{\pi/ 2} \int _0^{2}\int _0^{\sqrt {4-r^2 \cos^2\theta}}dzrdrd\theta $$