# Solving the definite integral $\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{(1+x)\sqrt{4x+1}-3x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve the definite integral: $$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{(1+x)\sqrt{4x+1}-3x+1}dx$$ The integral was proposed by my algebraic geometry professor as a warm up excercise, he hinted us to research about elliptic functions and curves, but I cannot find anything related to this integral. I tried substition and integration by parts, by I can't seem to reduce the problem.

I already solved the integral already by proving the convergence of it Taylor Series around $x_0=2$ and integrating said power series. But, its only an approximation, since I can't integrate infinite terms.

Is it possible to solve it analytically? What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your query to show **all** of your work, including failed efforts down paths that didn't work.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.

Comment: I couldn't find an analytic form, but numerical integration yields $3.23568$, which you might use to check an eventual answer.

Comment: Might be helpful to work with arcsin: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533082/integral-of-sqrt1-x2-using-integration-by-parts

Comment: As far as I got, with $4x+1=(u+1)^2$ we get $$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2(u+1)\sqrt{u^3+8}\:du$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi. I do not understand how could be asked this kind of questions ? Do you ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I hope some expert in elliptic curves can provide us a with suitable rational substitution to get the integral evaluated in terms of gamma functions. But this is something a professor shouldn't ask students as a warm up exercise. At least I am not getting warmed up.

Comment: Mathematica answer: $$4 \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{11}{6};\frac{4}{3};-1\right)+\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{13}{6};\frac{5}{3};-1\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a nightmare, look at the antiderivative given by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1+-+3*x+%2B+%281+%2B+x%29*Sqrt%5B1+%2B+4*x%5D%5D%2Cx%5D). If you like elliptic integrals and complex numbers, I suppose that you are more than happy.

Using the integration bounds, the result is just a monster. Numerically,
$$I=3.23567625418595545329101113302458555831569511979865687\cdots$$

Interesting (for the fun) is that an inverse symbolic calculator proposes, as an *approximation*, the reciprocal of the smallest root of the cubic equation
$$15572 x^3+13982 x^2-78333 x+22414=0$$

This is in a relative error of $3.1\times 10^{-19}$.